# ¿Como puedo concatenar columnas en excel?

Tags: excel

¡Hola!, resulta que necesito combinar o concatenar columnas para que la informacion de esas columnas se pasen a la columna que deseo , por ejemplo quiero que en la columna C , este la información de la columna D,E,F , y que la columna C tome todo el espacio necesario para contener esta información , adjunto imagen de ejemplo :
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

De antemano Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Deberías añadir código para que podamos ayudarte [ask] - [tour]

Comment: Hola Oscar! Gracias por la respuesta! , es solamente juntar columnas de excel no hay nada de codigo! Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es juntar la info de `D`, `E` y `F` en la columna `C`, deberías utilizar la función `CONCATENAR`.

Te quedaría `=CONCATENAR(D2;E2;F2)`

En tu caso en la columna `C` te completaría como: **MuñozCalfualDurante**

Si quieres añadir espacios entre cada info puedes poner `;" "` entre cada dato.

Quedaría `=CONCATENAR(D2;" ";E2;" ";F2)`

En tu caso en la columna `C` te completaría como: **Muñoz Calfual Durante**